# How to verify delays between signals using UVM?

Tags: system-verilog, uvm

I have a number of signals that I would like to verify the delay between them.

For example, lets define register with the name X_Y_DELAY which configure the time should pass from the rise of X signal to Y signal.

I want to make sure that the value I write to the X_Y_DELAY register is really the time between the signal increases.

I wonder if the right way is to do it through the uvm scoreboard or through the monitor while the signals arrive?

Thanks

Comment: It depends what the delay is. If it's a delay of less than the duration of one transaction, then it ought to be the monitor doing this checking. If it's a delay that results in two separate transactions, then probably the scoreboard should be checking.

Comment: Hi, first of all thanks for your comment. Actually my only goal is to check those registered delays on few signals. I have no reason to bring those signals to SB but only to check those timing configurations. That`s why I am wondering if I should monitor the signals and make a transactions to the SB of item that is actually holds the delay values and then in the SB compare it to the registers value. Or doing all of this right in the monitor without send any transaction to SB.

Answer (score 1):

This is really best done in an assertion within the interface itself.